Simplify an expression with a dot product with 0
The post below explain my problem, but here is a simple example:
$Assumptions (k) \[Element] Vectors[2]
FullSimplify[Series[A k . k, {k, 0, 0}]]

gives:
A (0 . 0) + O[k]^1

instead of 0. How to simplify this? I cannot find a 0 vector in mathematica.
Note that doing the change of variable k-> K*eps and expanding eps, sometimes work, sometime does not.

Original post
I'm trying to compute a taylor expansion with vector:
Clear[k, qI, q]
$Assumptions = (q | k | qI | Q | K) \[Element] Vectors[2]
f[q_] = Sqrt[q . q];
Co[q_, w_] = f[q]^2/(w^2 + f[q]^6);
Go[q_, w_] = 1/(-I*w + f[q]^3);
g[k_, q_, p_] = f[k]*q . p;

A = Assuming[{\[Alpha] > 0, \[Gamma] > 0}, 
  Integrate[
    Co[qI - q, wi]*Go[k - qI, -wi]*Go[qI, wi]*g[k, qI, k - qI]*
     g[qI, q, qI - q]*g[k - qI, -qI + q, k - q], {wi, -Infinity, 
     Infinity}]/(2 Pi)]

q = Q*eps;
k = K*eps;
FullSimplify[Series[A, {eps, 0, 0}] // Normal] 

I'm not too sure about how to do a taylor expansion in small vector q and k. So I tried with a small parameter eps. Anyway, the result of FullSimplify contains terms like:
eps Q 0 . 0 0 . qI (-qI) . 0 (-qI) . (-qI) qI . (-qI)
which should be 0. However, I could not find a way to get rid of them. I could do it by hand but I think the lowest term in the expansion is at a high order. I also tried to use TensorExpand after using Series but a division with 0 (that should be cancelled I think) messes up everything. If it is used inside the Series, Mathematica does not manage to terminate the computation.
Any help is appreciated!

I don't think Series works for symbolic Tensor or Vectors. Try putting A = Array[a, {2, 2}] and so on.
